# Add my appengine application to Moodle

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, moodle

I'm new with moodle in fact create java application using GWT and deployed it to appengine, really it was about keystroke authentication in which detect the unauthorized users from their typing behavior on keyboard, so I make a text area that takes some data form key and send it to the server side and make some comparisons with data in the app store, i found that it would be Awesome if i add that to module meanwhile this application is my graduation project so when i integrate with moodle it is useful point for me. My question is how can i integrate my application to moodle taking in consideration that i use the appstore .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into something called IMS LTI. Here is a good video introduction to it:

http://vimeo.com/14100773

Before IMS LTI in order to hook into Moodle you needed to write a Moodle plugin. But using IMS LTI you should be able to just enter in some details about your app, like the url and a shared key and using IMS LTI user data and responses should be passed between Moodle and your app. Future versions of the IMS LTI standard will also allow you to pass grading information.